# Calculating Expectation of Exponential with Indicator Functions (Continuous Time Martingales)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

**Update:** So it turns out that the question I was given is actually wrong! $X_t$ should be defined with $\{T>t\}$ not $\{T<t\}$.

---

My question is the following. It looks really easy, and so I 'just did it'... getting a completely difference answer. I'm clearly doing something rather stupid, but I can't for the life of me see what!

> Let $T \sim \text{Exp}(1)$. Set $X_t = e^t 1_{\{T<t\}}$. Show that
>   $$E(X_t1_{\{T>r\}}) = E(X_s1_{\{T>r\}}) \; \text{for} \ r \le s \le t.$$

Here's what I've done:

> $$E(X_t1_{T>r}) = E(e^t1_{r<T<t}) = e^tP(r<T<t) = e^t(e^{-r}-e^{-t}) = e^{t-r}-1,$$
>   $$E(X_s1_{T>r}) = E(e^s1_{r<T<s}) = e^sP(r<T<s) = e^s(e^{-r}-e^{-s}) = e^{s-r}-1.$$
>   Thus the two aren't equal...

Any advice on this would be most appreciated!

---

Just before this, the question asks to describe the natural filtration of $X$. It then goes on after to ask to deduce that $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a cadlag martingale. That should be fine: just use the fact that the indicator functions will form a $\pi$ system containing the $\sigma$-algebra and apply Dynkin's lemma (or something like that) -- that's not the important bit of this SE question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your calculation is correct (there is a typo in the 2nd line, 2nd "=", it should read $e^s$ instead of $e^t$). It implies that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale. In fact, that's the best we can expect as $\mathbb{E}X_t$ is (strictly) increasing. (Note that $\mathbb{E}X_0=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_t)= e^t \mathbb{P}(T<t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.)

Comment: Typo corrected -- it was a typo, not a mistake in my calculation. Here's a link to the question: [Q4.3, Page 2](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/apex2.pdf).

Comment: @SmileySam The question states that $X_t = e^t 1_{t<T}$ ... you defined $X_t = e^t 1_{T<t}$.

Comment: The question states that *now*... I emailed my lecturer once it became apparent that it wasn't just that I was being slow -- ie when you got the same result as me, and it's a very easy result. He's now updated it online. :)

Comment: Shall I close(/delete) this question, since it's now not relevant? I'd lose 10 reputation -- big whoopy-do... =P

Comment: @SmileySam I see :). Well, it's your decision whether you want to delete it or not. Usually, it is considered impolite to delete a question as soon as someone has written an answer; however, in this case it didn't take me hours to write the answer, so I don't mind too much.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't normally delete a question at all, it's just a fairly pointless question. I'll leave it up for a bit in case someone else doing the sheet doesn't get the correction and then sees it!

Comment: I agree about deletion in general: I've answered questions, and then the person never does anything with the question again or deletes it, and it all seems a bit futile. =P -- I eve had one person comment on each answer saying "this doesn't answer the question as it doesn't give the full details" -- the answers gave the method, but not details calculations -- he basically just wanted a solution so he didn't have to think. Some of us added some more details and we never heard from him again! (Rant over ;).)